# R problems with scale_color_discrete()

Tags: r

I am writing a script that is supposed to be able to read in a large dataset and plot the results.

Script:

```
paths <- list.files(path = path, pattern="\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

dataset <- data.frame()

for (x in paths) {  
   t <- fread(file)  
   dataset <- rbind(dataset, t)  
}  

mapping <- aes(
  x = column_c 
  , color = column_a
  , linetype = column_b
)

plot <- (ggplot(data=dataset, mapping=mapping)
         + stat_ecdf()
         + scale_color_discrete(name = "COL_A", breaks = c(1, 2, 3))
         + scale_linetype_discrete(name = "COL_B", breaks = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"))        
)
```

The dataset has three columns: `column_a`, `column_b`, `column_c` 
In `column_a` possible values are: 1, 2, 3 (type: integer)
In `column_b` possible values are: `aaa`, `bbb`, `cccc` (type: character)
In `column_c` different values in range (0,1000) (type:integer)

***Problem:*** To organize the plot, I use in `aes` the color parameter to be based on `column_a`, and the line parameter to be based on `column_b`. The plotted graph seems to accept the line type command but it ignores the `color = column_a`.  It doesn't show any error message, it just seems it doesn't show any different color lines. They are all the same color.
This leads me to the conclusion that it either doesn't recognize the breaks.
To check this out I preformed the following command:

> unique(dataset$column_a)

and I got as return

> [1]     2     3 1
>   So, I would say that the dataset does contain the breaks that I have set to be expected in line

```
 + scale_color_discrete(name = "COL_A", breaks = c(1, 2, 3))
```

Does someone notice what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE:
class(dataset)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: I believe the first one  dataset <- data.frame() is useless...  The last one that dataset in the end is of type list, I have double checked it with typeof()

Comment: Don't use `typeof`, it's pretty much always useless. Use `class()` or `str()` to get info about an object.

Comment: ggplot considers numbers as continuous. If you want a discrete scale, convert the column to `factor`. Try `dataset$column_a = factor(dataset$column_a)`

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information not to use typeof(). I have posted the values I got with class(dataset)

Comment: If that doesn't work, please post a bit of reproducible sample data... `dput(dataset[1:20, ])` would be nice.

Comment: That solved the problem! thank you... if you want you can write it as solution, so I can mark it

Comment: One other side comment - `rbind` in a loop is an anti-pattern that is very inefficient. You'd be better off with `dataset = lapply(paths, fread)` and then `dataset = dplyr::bind_rows(dataset)` or `dataset = data.table::rbindlist(dataset)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a discrete scale, the column needs to be a `factor` or `character` class. Numeric (including integer) will have a discrete scale.